# "Cancel Enabled" option not present in Uninstaller Screen

Tags: install4j

While working on Uninstaller using install4j i came across a problem . In Installation screen there is one configuration field "Cancel enabled" ,which when enabled , we can cancel the Installation on "Installation in progress screen" (when components are getting installed).

In Uninstaller, on "Welcome Uninstallation" the cancel button works.
But on Uninstallation screen , there is no such field("Cancel enabled") present in configuration.This results that we cannot cancel the Uninstallation (when components are getting uninstalled). Is there any way to make this happen? (When we click on "Cancel" button it should exit uninstaller).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the installer, the uninstaller has no rollback functionality, so cancelling the uninstallation would leave the installation in a broken state.

Comment: Thank you . It explains the situation.